# What's a word for someone who "jumps on the bandwagon"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word (*the* word, as I know it exists, but I cannot remember it) that characterizes a person who blindly follows the crowd. It is a noun, and I believe it starts with an L – monosyllabic – disparaging – might fit nicely in the phrase: the _________ of Wall Street.

Comment: *Lemming*, perhaps?

Comment: as soon as I turned my head away from the screen I remembered it. And by then you had already answered. thank you, kindly!

Comment: *Lemming* is definitely the word that literally means what you were asking about. In modern practice, typically informally, a lot of people might call them a *sheep*, meaning that they are blindly following the shepherd (whomever or whatever the shepherd might be).